# How do you inject com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache via Spring?

Tags: java, spring

This is how my cache is instantiated:

```
return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(10)
                .expireAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build()
```

How can I configure Spring to perform dependency injection?

```
<bean id="matchedDFUCache" class="com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine" factory-method="newBuilder"></bean>
```

is giving me this error:

```
[coral:launch] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'realTimeForecastFactory': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'matchedDFUCache' is expected to be of type 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache' but was actually of type 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine'
```

This is the source file: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine.java

Comment: It is in the error message - return class name is `Cache` not `Caffeine`. Just change the class attribute in ur xml to what the error message says

Answer (score 0):

```
        <bean id="caffeineBuilder" class="com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine" factory-method="newBuilder">
        </bean>
        <bean id="matchedDFUCache" factory-bean="caffeineBuilder" factory-method="build">
        </bean>
```